# Problem with files on a mounted CIFS filesystem

Tags: centos, mount, cifs

We do have several servers (CentOS 7) with the same CIFS storage, and have an issue with the files created on one server, and unstable after that.

The process is

1. server1 is creating data on /DATA/CARTO_TEST
2. server1 is calling server2 API to configure a new image warehouse
3. server2 is accessing to the same /DATA/CARTO_TEST files

But we encounter this problem on step 3 :

```
2021-09-22 13:15:30,042 WARN [shapefile.shp] - Could not open the .shx file, continuing assuming the .shp file is not sparse
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /DATA/CARTO_TEST/TEST_LEVEL5/pyramid/2/2.shx (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:345)
```

We are experiencing strange behaviour after generating the data on our CIFS storage :

```
[geoproc@server1 pyramid]$ cd 10/
[geoproc@server1 10]$ ls -al
total 17
drwxr-xr-x 2 geoproc geoproc   0 Sep 29 11:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 geoproc geoproc   0 Sep 29 11:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 geoproc geoproc   0 Sep 28 10:57 1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc  65 Sep 29 11:13 10.dbf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc  13 Sep 29 11:13 10.fix
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc 929 Sep 29 11:13 10.prj
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc 100 Sep 29 11:13 10.shp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc 100 Sep 29 11:13 10.shx

[geoproc@server1 10]$ rm 10.*
rm: cannot remove ‘10.shp’: No such file or directory

[geoproc@server1 10]$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 geoproc geoproc   0 Sep 29 11:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 geoproc geoproc   0 Sep 29 11:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 geoproc geoproc   0 Sep 28 10:57 1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc  65 Sep 29 11:13 10.dbf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc 929 Sep 29 11:13 10.prj
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc 100 Sep 29 11:13 10.shp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc 100 Sep 29 11:13 10.shx

[geoproc@server1 10]$ rm 10.*
rm: cannot remove ‘10.dbf’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘10.prj’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘10.shp’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘10.shx’: No such file or directory

[geoproc@server1 10]$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 geoproc geoproc   0 Sep 29 11:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 geoproc geoproc   0 Sep 29 11:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 geoproc geoproc   0 Sep 28 10:57 1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc  65 Sep 29 11:13 10.dbf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc 929 Sep 29 11:13 10.prj
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc 100 Sep 29 11:13 10.shp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 geoproc geoproc 100 Sep 29 11:13 10.shx

[geoproc@server1 10]$ cat 10.prj
cat: 10.prj: No such file or directory
```

The CIFS storage is mounted with these option on our servers server1 and server2 :

```
//<servername>/<share>$/GEOSERVER /DATA/CARTO_TEST cifs vers=2.0,noserverino,username=<username>,password=<password>,domain=<domaine name>,uid=<uid>,gid=<gid> 0 0
```

We can also read this in var/log/messages , but are not sure if it is related or not :

```
kernel: CIFS VFS: DFS capability contradicts DFS flag
```

Has anyone encounter a similar problem ?

Do you have any suggestion on

- What is the root cause of the problem ?
- How to solve it ?

We tried with and without noserverino option in the mount : no difference

We tried our generation on local file : no problem here

Comment: Interesting problem. Some thoughts. Could you elaborate: is this CIFS storage a Windows share on a _third_ server, or is this a Samba SMB share on `server1` or `server2`? If it's Windows: do you have event log entries that could help? If it's Linux/Samba: do you have (debug) logging enabled in Samba? Could file locking be a problem here?

Comment: It is a netapp that delivers an "ontap - svm" share. It is not mounted on a windows server, but directly accessible by windows users.
We did analyze  the netapp logs files, but did not found errors or locks.